# Android speed of ArrayList vs Database

Tags: java, android, performance, sqlite, arraylist

I have to store 500-1000 values in somewhere, but i cant decide which one is more efficient(***ArrayList*** vs ***Database***).Can you explain pros and cons of arraylist and database?

thanks...

Comment: They are two absolutely different things. An `ArrayList` or generally any `List` is not persistent, unlike a database which is.

Comment: 2 different concepts : ArrayList stores in memory so it is faster but doesn't allow for retrieval of data between launches of the app.

Answer (score 2):

In memory data structures are always faster than DB.

But tradeoff is between size of data structure and available memory. For your need, arraylist will be faster. But data will be gone once application is stopped or killed.
Database is persistent data store. If your need is to store temp data then arraylist is suitable and if you need to store it permanently then you have 2 options:

1. Database (standard way, API availalbe, standard practice)
2. Filesystem (keep your data in data structure till application stops and then write it to a file in encrypted form if security is required.)

If you need, explore about in memory databases for android(sqlite). This is best suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

the use of array list and the data base is different.

if u doesn't want to store your record permanently then you can use "Array List", but if u want to store your record   permanently then u need to use data base. 
because when you store the record in Array list those record stored into RAM. records don't  store into the secondary storage. but when you store the record in to the data base then records stores into the database.

if your concern about the speed of accessing the data from Array List or data base then arrayList is faster then the database